# Retrieving data from database with PHP using SQL - Error when using DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the problematic piece of code:

```
      <?php 
            include_once("database.php");

            $getmtn = $db->prepare("select distinct from mount_category");
            $getmtn->execute();
            $getCategory=$getmtn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

            foreach($getCategory as $cat)
            echo"<a href='$cat->category.php'>
              <div class='col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4' data-aos='fade-up'>
                <div class='listing-item'>
                  <div class='listing-image'>
                    <img src='images/$cat->category.jpg' alt='Image' class='img-fluid'>
                  </div>
                  <div class='listing-item-content'>
                    <h2 class='mb-1'><a href=''>$cat->category</a></h2>
                    <a class='px-4 mb-1 category bg-primary' href='$cat->category.php'>Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div></a>"
            ?>
```

If I write

```
$getmtn = $db->prepare("select * from mount_category");
```

The code will work just fine

But when I write

```
$getmtn = $db->prepare("select distinct from mount_category");
```

The page doesn't load as it should, instead, it shows this error:

```
Fatal error
: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'from mount_category' at line 1 in /home/60093552/public_html/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/OPEN INDEX FIRST/category.php:91 Stack trace: #0 /home/60093552/public_html/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/OPEN INDEX FIRST/category.php(91): PDO->prepare('select distinct...') #1 {main} thrown in
/home/60093552/public_html/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/mnkljmnk/OPEN INDEX FIRST/category.php
on line
91
```

Line 91 is the "distinct / *" line.

Comment: You forgot the `*` in your failing query.  (Or to specify the columns being selected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `distinct` keyword is reserved in MySQL, you need to use backticks in order to prevent that.

```
$getmtn = $db->prepare("select `distinct` from mount_category");
```

If I understood incorrecly and you don't have a distinct columns in your table, than you need to specify a column. The `distinct` keywords act as a unique filter for a particular column, so you have to specify a column.

Comment: Yeah I don't have a column called "distinct", I just wanted to retrieve data without it repeating. Thanks, that worked.
Here is the fixed code for whoever visits this question:

            `$getmtn = $db->prepare("select distinct category from mount_category");
            $getmtn->execute();
            $getCategory=$getmtn->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);`